# Modal unica para linhas de uma DATA TABLE

Tags: php, html, laravel, modal

Tenho uma listagem de dados com aproximadamente 1200 clientes onde trago [CPF, NOME, TELEFONE, UM STATUS] e uma coluna com os botões de controle, a um ano fiz um mini-curso na faculdade para aprender a trabalhar com Laravel, o instrutor ensinou a fazer de uma forma que ao meu agora está inviável pelo tempo de carregamento!

PROBLEMA:

Para cada controle tenho um link que me leva a alguma ação no controller, como editar, remover e copiar, nesta DATA TABLE em questão tenho mais uma ação que é definir se aquele cliente paga ou não descarga de produtos. Para os botões de remover e o de pagamento de descarga tem **uma modal para cada em cada linha** então imagina o tamanho do código html!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente eu personalizo o titulo da modal, o corpo (com dados do objeto no foreach) e o botão de ação (id da linha enviando para o controller via rota do tipo get)

Código do botão e da modal (Remover) :

```html
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" title="Remover parceiro" data-toggle="modal" href="#modalRemove{{$c->parc_cpf_cnpj}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalRemove{{$c->parc_cpf_cnpj}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                                        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><img clas="logoApplication" src={{ asset(\App\Http\Controllers\ConfigController::logoAplication())}} width="30" height="30"> &nbsp; {{ \App\Http\Controllers\HelperMsgController::remove_registro() }}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <p class="attention-removal">
          <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;
          <b>{{\App\Http\Controllers\HelperMsgController::msg_body_modal_selec_remove_exclamation()}}</b>
        </p>
        <p>Deseja realmente remover definitivamente o parceiro <b>{{$c->parc_razao_social}}</b> ?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" title="Cancelar operação" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>&nbsp; Cancelar
                                                                        </button>

        <a id="remover_form_rec{{$c->id}}" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" title="Remover este parceiro" href="{{action('ParceiroController@destroy', $c->parc_cpf_cnpj)}}">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp; Remover</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tentei implementar o ajax, mas não consigo de forma satisfatória:

```
function geraModalConfDescarga(parc_cpf_cnpj) {
        var path = 'modal/confirma/'+parc_cpf_cnpj+'/pagamento/descarga';
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: path,
            dataType: 'HTML',
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (response) {
                //adiciona o modal (content do view na div .content)
                $(".content").append(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

No botão da DATA TABLE:

```html
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" title="Confirmar pagamento de descarga" data-toggle="modal" onclick="geraModalConfDescarga({{$c->parc_cpf_cnpj}})" href="#modalConfPagDesc{{$c->parc_cpf_cnpj}}">
  <i class="fa fa-money"></i> <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</a>
```

Na rota:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'modal', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function (){
Route::get('confirma/{id}/pagamento/descarga', 'ModalsController@modalParceiroPagaDescarga');});
```

No controller:

```
public function modalParceiroPagaDescarga($id)
{
    $parceiro = Parceiro::where("parc_cpf_cnpj", "=", intval($id))->get()->first();

    $parc_cpf_cnpj = $parceiro->parc_cpf_cnpj;
    $parc_razao_social = $parceiro->parc_razao_social;

    return view("modals.pag-descarga", compact('parc_cpf_cnpj', 'parc_razao_social'));
}
```

A modal em um arquivo php:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalConfPagDesc{{$parc_cpf_cnpj}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><img clas="logoApplication" src={{ asset(\App\Http\Controllers\ConfigController::logoAplication())}} width="30" height="30"> &nbsp; {{ \App\Http\Controllers\HelperMsgController::confirma() }}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <p>Deseja realmente confirmar que o parceiro <b>{{$parc_razao_social}}</b> efetua pagamento de desscargas ?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" title="Cancelar operação" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>&nbsp; Cancelar
                </button>

        <a id="confirmar_descarga{{$parc_cpf_cnpj}}" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" title="Confirmar pagamento de descarga" href="{{action('ParceiroController@confirmPagDescarga', $parc_cpf_cnpj)}}">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp; Confirmar</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#confirmar_descarga{{$parc_cpf_cnpj}}').click(function(event) {
      $('#modalConfPagDesc{{$parc_cpf_cnpj}}').modal('hide');
      window.setInterval('abreProcessamento()', 400);
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Ajax apenas um Modal, cria a url e coloca no action

Comment: Como? tentei implementar de uma forma que encontrei, se eu digito na URL o caminho com o parâmetro, executa, mas pleo ajax dá pagina 404!

Comment: Consegui! faltou uma "barra" antes do nome do modal

Answer (score -1):

Para ter um resultado melhor no front end você pode tentar utilizar uma outra abordagem como usar o Vuejs que é recomendado pelo proprio laravel.

O vue permite que você crie aplicações mais dinamicas usando menos codigo e com uma maior facilidade.

[Link da documentação do laravel usando vue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend)

[Esse video pode te ajudar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cxtm5u-SVNs)